# Volterra Processes (integration wrt Brownian motion): reference request

Tags: reference-request, integration, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I need some references about Volterra processes $Y=(Y_t)_{t\geq0}$ defined as
$$ Y_t:=\int_{0}^{t} g(t,s)dB_s, \ \ t\geq 0,$$

where $B=\left(B_t\right)_{t\geq0}$ is a brownian motion and $g$ satisfies
$\int_{0}^{t} g(t,s)^2ds<\infty$.

Even general references on the integration of deterministic functions wrt Brownian motion would be fine.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? References about what kinds of properties?

Comment: Basic theoretical fact.

Answer (score 1):

one source of many references about Voltera processes and a stochastic calculus for them is in

["Stochastic integration with respect to Volterra processes"](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_2005__41_2_123_0.pdf) by L. Decreusefond.